# Read a text file with NSURL in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsurl

I want to read and display the content of a text file that is located at an URL.
I am coding a Mac App for Yosemite and I need to use Swift but I stuck on this.

Here is my code:

```
let messageURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/text.txt")
let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(messageURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        var urlContents = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

        println((urlContents))


    })
```

I tried to do it with NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL but it seems to be deprecated on OS X 10.10.

The text file located at on the server has only one line (UTF8).

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you call `downloadTask.resume()`?

```
let messageURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/text.txt")
let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(messageURL!,
        completionHandler: { 
          (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

             var urlContents = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

             println(urlContents)

    })
downloadTask.resume() // Call it and you should be able to see the text.txt content
```

Comment: What about if the url is pointing to local file like "file:///Users/adrian/desktop/readme.txt"?

Comment: @AdrianHoe: For that you can just use String(contentsOf:URL).  In fact, you can probably use that to retrieve remote URLs, but I haven't tried.