# Fatal error when trying to read text from a url

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to use the code from [Read a text file with NSURL in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797899/read-a-text-file-with-nsurl-in-swift/26798333#26798333?newreg=8c0ebacdb90041b88eacfbc0734c58df) but when I do I get a fatal error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on the line that declares `urlContents`

> Code

```
let messageURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/text.txt")
let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(messageURL!,
        completionHandler: {
            (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            var urlContents = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

            println(urlContents)

    })
downloadTask.resume()
```

Comment: The first step should be to check the value of `error` in the completion handler ...

Comment: Also check that `NSURL(string: ...)` is actually returning an object. That method returns an optional `NSURL` so it could be `nil`.

Comment: Im not sure if NSURL supports "localhost" change to 127.0.0.1 and it might remove the error.

Comment: @Arbitur No need to do this, `localhost` works with NSURL.

Comment: @EricD. Ok Well something is making that NSURL nil

Comment: @AdamPro13 I just checked that, messageURL is not nil

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I am new to OS X and swift, how do I do that.

Comment: What line does this error happen on? Does it get into the completion block?

Comment: @AdamPro13 it was happening on the var urlContents... line, I reset the simulator and it fixed the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Voting to close as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced".